# Because I cannot find the root verb in any dictionary, what does をしめて回った mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, kanji, syntax, kana

This is from a Manga, or so I heard.

中学時代に地元の学校をしめて回ったマキちゃん。

Maki-chan squeezed around a/some local school in the era/period during junior high school.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/translator/comments/j7d9aa/japanese_english_excerpt_from_a_manga_page/

Answer (score 2):

This シメる is a slangy verb that euphemistically means something like "to chastise (thus making them understand who is the strongest)" or "to give someone a (harsh) lesson (about underground rules, etc)". Usually brute force is implied. It's 締める in kanji, but normally written with katakana. This ～て回る is just "go to various places (doing ～)". So this girl went to many schools in the area, challenged school delinquents, defeated them and dominated them.

- [日本語俗語辞書: シメる](http://zokugo-dict.com/12si/simeru.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the help!